# Extend Desktop to Monitor over LAN

Tags: linux, networking, multiple-monitors, xorg

I want to make use of an old laptop by extending my the desktop from my main PC onto the monitor of this other, old laptop over a LAN connection.

I've looked into [Xdmx/dmx](http://dmx.sourceforge.net), but the project seems to have been dead for a while.

Are there any other alternatives or will I have to cobble my own script together?

Comment: Have you tried Xdmx? Arch has it in their repositories and people have it working [as late as a year ago](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=111412).

Comment: Like i said, I've looked into it but I use Ubuntu and the package is broken and the source repo from the website is empty :/

Comment: Did you report it as a bug?

Comment: Yaha, although it seems to be fixed in 12.04

Comment: cross-post. and the best answer on https://askubuntu.com/questions/136942/extend-desktop-to-monitor-over-lan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A hackish solution would be to extend your desktop to dual X displays on your main machine, with `DISPLAY=:0` being your main screen and `DISPLAY=:1` being to the right. Run `x11vnc` to share display 1 and then run a barebones client on the laptop with a VNC viewer that connects to display 1 over Ethernet and projects it full screen.