# Use Laptop as monitor (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: ubuntu, multiple-monitors, vnc, ubuntu-18.04, vncserver

I have two laptops, both with Ubuntu installed. In the same network, I want one of them to be converted to simply be a monitor (like a slave for the main laptop, but not only share keyboard and mouse like barrier, it should become a slave, in other words i should be able to drag and drop in the other monitor).

Thanks.

Comment: You may find this alternative useful: https://symless.com/synergy

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extend Desktop to Monitor over LAN](https://superuser.com/questions/424410/extend-desktop-to-monitor-over-lan)

Comment: Agree with @K7AAY on Synergy. Last time I used it I had a relatively early version but it still offered the cool capability to hook up via network to another machine and be able to have it display stuff transferred over the network rather than cables.

Comment: I Guys, tks for the rxeply. Honestly i was searching for a free tool. @K7AAY i've tried with Xdmx but in new versions seems to be broken...the only thing that i have not tried is to install the .deb version on ubuntu

Comment: You indicate the problem is solved by [accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 5):

[Synergy](https://symless.com/synergy) is a $30-$40 commercial supported open source app (you can [download the source code](https://members.symless.com/forums/topic/5068-source-code-for-version-2/?tab=comments#comment-22223) to compile and build it yourself) which does this.

Free? There's a free fork of Synergy, named [Barrier](https://github.com/debauchee/barrier/blob/master/README.md) ([review](https://alternativeto.net/software/barrier/about/)) with [a package for 18.04](https://repology.org/repository/ubuntu_18_04) and [now 20.04](https://repology.org/repository/ubuntu_20_04).

[x2vnc](http://fredrik.hubbe.net/x2vnc.html) is also available and requires [x2x](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/x2x.1.html) or [x11vnc](http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/) on the subordinate PC, but unlike Barrier, it's out of maintenance.

Comment: But the thing is that both of them do 'same mouse/keyboard for multiple PCs' .My goal is the principle of xdmx so, share the session between two laptop. One Laptop ,the slave, becomes an extension.

Comment: it's broken for my ubuntu version, if i'll find another solution, i'll ping you :)

Comment: REFUND ME. NOW.

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION HERE.
I've found this project (is not with MIT Licensed but it's pretty cool).

The principle is :

1. Create a virtual screen and start x11 (this is done by [VirtScreen](https://github.com/kbumsik/VirtScreen/blob/master/README.md))
2. from the slave laptop connect via viewer (i'm using [vncViewer](https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/download/viewer/))

Answer (score 1):

## Virtual Monitor Over VNC

Similar to a couple of answers given, I was able to get it working using [x11vnc](http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/) by means of using my own code derived from the [VNC Virtual Display Linker](https://github.com/mrenrich84/vnc_virtual_display_linker) python code. I had a couple of issues with this code but I managed to get it working as shown below.

### Simplified Intructions:

Please be aware of the notes and considerations at the end of this answer.

1. **Definitions:** The "server" will be the computer which screen you want to extend, the "client" will be the computer (or tablet, any device able to deploy a VNC client) that you want to use as a screen.
2. **Required Software**: On the server install `x11vnc` and `gtf`, on the client install a vnc client.
3. You need to know client's screen size (we'll call them: `CLIENT_WIDTH`, `CLIENT_HEIGHT`) and the servers' screen size (we'll call them: `SERVER_WIDTH`, `SERVER_HEIGHT`).
4. In the server, run in a terminal `gtf CLIENT_WIDTH CLIENT_HEIGHT 60` (replace the `CLIENT_WIDTH` and `CLIENT_HEIGHT` with the corresponding values). As an example for `gtf CLIENT_WIDTH CLIENT_HEIGHT 60` is

```
# 1384x768 @ 60.00 Hz (GTF) hsync: 47.70 kHz; pclk: 86.62 MHz
Modeline "1384x768_60.00"  86.62  1384 1456 1600 1816  768 769 772 795  -HSync +Vsync
```

5. From the previous result copy what is in front of `Modeline`, (in this case `"1384x768_60.00"  86.62  1384 1456 1600 1816  768 769 772 795  -HSync +Vsync`) and use that as a parameter to `xrandr --newmode` command. For example, in this case, we'll have to run in the server `xrandr --newmode "1368x768_60.00"  85.86  1368 1440 1584 1800  768 769 772 795  -HSync +Vsync`
6. In 5 we've created a newmode in `xrandr`, now we need to add it to the virtual screen, as follows `xrandr --addmode VIRTUAL1 "1368x768_60.00"` (please remember to use your own newly created mode name, which is the value including quotes in 5).
7. Run `x11vnc -usepw -nocursorshape -nocursorpos -noxinerama -solid -repeat -forever -clip CLIENT_WIDTHxCLIENT_HEIGHT+SERVER_WIDTH+0`. As an example: `x11vnc -usepw -nocursorshape -nocursorpos -noxinerama -solid -repeat -forever -clip 1368x768+1920+0`. This will create a VNC server in port `5900` you can connect to.
8. Lastly, connect to the server from you other computer (or any VNC client, recommended `krdc` for linux machines). You should be able to enjoy your extended screen now.

### Notes and considerations:

- In step 8, with krdc, it is recommended to use the "Medium Quality" option, even if you are on cable: both the "Low" and "High" quality options produce errors.
- I tried this over a WiFi network and it works properly, however on cable it's smoother.
- I had problems when starting the VNC server in step 7, the screen started to flicker and I couldn't see what I was doing on the screen. To fix this, I connected via the VNC server (the extended screen already works at this point), opened the `Displays` tool (the one that comes with the system where you can see the displays that are connected) and `Unify Outputs` then `Break Unified Outputs`
  (an example of this option in Kubuntu is shown below). Then everything worked.

[image: Unify Outputs]

Comment: Thanks for such an excellent and extensive description!

Answer (score 0):

If you are having trouble with your graphics card virtual screen,
you can use a dummy hdmi device.

In my case, since I have at hand hdmi2vga adapter, I connect the pins with some resistors as described here:
https://www.geeks3d.com/20170609/simple-display-emulator-with-an-hdmi-vga-adapter/

Once the dummy device is detected, adjust its resolution to match the resolution of the slave laptop.

Run x11vnc at the server:
x11vnc -ncache 10 -usepw -nocursorshape -nocursorpos  -solid -repeat -forever -clip xinerama1

At the slave laptop: run remmina and connect to the server as medium quality

Note: I'm using Ubuntu 20.04